# How to make bigger a matrix inside a chain of equations?

Tags: equations, formatting, matrices, arrays, size

let us consider my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\label{eq:CR3BP:state:transition:matrix} 
\vec{\Phi}= \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial \vec{x}_0} = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\[0.2cm]
    \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right] =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \vec{\Phi}_{11} & \vec{\Phi}_{12} \\[0.2cm]
    \vec{\Phi}_{21} & \vec{\Phi}_{22} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

I want to increase the size of the red circled matrix because the symbols of partial derivatives are too small.
Can you show how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to add `\displaystyle`

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & 
    \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\
    \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & 
    \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} 
  \end{array} } \right] 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    {\displaystyle\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{r}_0}} &
    {\displaystyle\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{v}_0}} \\[0.3cm]
    {\displaystyle\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{r}_0}} &
    {\displaystyle\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{v}_0}}
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use `\dfrac` (`\displaystyle \frac`) or `\mfrac` of `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

With \verb|\frac|:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:CR3BP:state:transition:matrix} 
\vec{\Phi}= \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial \vec{x}_0} = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\[0.2cm]
    \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right] =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \vec{\Phi}_{11} & \vec{\Phi}_{12} \\[0.2cm]
    \vec{\Phi}_{21} & \vec{\Phi}_{22} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation}


With \verb|\mfrac| of \textsf{nccmath}:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:CR3BP:state:transition:matrix} 
\vec{\Phi}= \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial \vec{x}_0} = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \mfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \mfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\[0.2cm]
    \mfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \mfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right] =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \vec{\Phi}_{11} & \vec{\Phi}_{12} \\[0.2cm]
    \vec{\Phi}_{21} & \vec{\Phi}_{22} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation}


With \verb|\dfrac|:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:CR3BP:state:transition:matrix} 
\vec{\Phi}= \frac{\partial \vec{x}}{\partial \vec{x}_0} = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \dfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \dfrac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\[0.2cm]
    \dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{r}_0} & \dfrac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial \vec{v}_0} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right] =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
    \vec{\Phi}_{11} & \vec{\Phi}_{12} \\[0.2cm]
    \vec{\Phi}_{21} & \vec{\Phi}_{22} \\ 
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]